# My head gasket was fixed but I still have a leakage

Tags: engine, cooling-system, head-gasket

I have a leakage, the cooling fluid reservoir is empty and some has leaked from the radiator.

I already fixed my head gasket that was leaking. Now the mechanic is telling me I need a new water pump, because that's where it is leaking from.

I replaced my water pump and timing belt in May 2014. Could that be the reason or did the mechanic do something not right?

Comment: What is the year/make/model/engine of the car?

Comment: Depending on the problem, *just* replacing the head gasket might not solve the problem. If the head or the block is cracked or warped, the gasket alone won't solve the problem.

Comment: These mechanics are stupid you can never really find a trustworthy one unless it’s your buddy but nah they had to had put bad material for the head gasket there is a specific material used for head gasket so they do not leak, he made just ordered a cheap one for your car overly charged you for it and slapped it on there good material should not make it leak after it has been repaired

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the timing belt would have been removed in order to facilitate the head gasket change.  It very much depends on the type of engine you have but I have frequently seen water pump failing to reseal after they've been removed and refitted.

Personally, I'd have changed the water pump (or at least the o-ring / seal / gasket) and the timing belt as part of the task of replacing a head gasket.  If definitely makes sense that the coolant could be disappearing thanks to a faulty water pump / water pump seal.

If you can give me specifics of the make,m model, year and engine type in your car I might be able to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility your mechanic did repair the wrong thing if there was no coolant in the oil (the oil turns grey/white if it gets mixed with water). If it was not, the head gasket might have been ok. You mention some leaking from the radiator. Have you replaced the radiator cap? Sometimes they leak. The leak might be in the radiator itself. If not, the water pump probably needs to be resealed or
replaced. If these suggestions don't fix it, you might get rid of a lot of cash as in some serious repair might be needed.